# AngularJS: Get attribute value in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i am a newbie of angularJS, i just want to ask how can i get value of on-success attribute which will have a JSON object on a successful upload request.
"on-success" attribute exists on post-creator.template.html page.

index.html

```
<body>
    <div>
        <post-creator post-id="0"></post-creator>
    </div>
</body>
```

This a post-creator.template.html

```
<form role="form">
                <div class="form-group float-label-control">
                    <label>Title</label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Name" class="form-control" ng-model="model.post.title">
                </div>

                <div upload-button
                     url="/user_uploads"
                     on-success="onSuccess(response)"
                     on-error="onError(response)"
                     ng-model="onSuccess(response)"
                     >Upload</div>

                <div class="text-center">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="model.save(model.post)">Save</button>
                </div>
            </form>
```

And this is post-creator.component.js:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    var module = angular.module(__appName);

    function controller($http) {
        var model = this;
        model.post = null;

        model.save = function (post) {
           //get on-success value here
           //console.log(model.onSuccess);
        }
    }

    module.component("postCreator", {
        templateUrl: "components/post-creator/post-creator.template.html",
        bindings: {
            category: "<",
            postId: "<",
            subCategory: "<"
        },
        controllerAs: "model",
        controller: ["$http", controller]
    });
}());
```

Comment: Question is unclear, would you mind to update it with more information with what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: I just want to get on-success value in my controller model.save function, when i click on save button.

Answer (score 0):

you can inject `$element` to your controller and get `attributes` binded to your directive by `$element[0].attributes`.

```
function controller($http, $element) {
  var attrs = $element[0].attributes;  
  // you own logic
}
```